# Cambiar Toolbar Background Color en una BottomBarPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xaml, toolbar, bottombar

Hola estoy tabajando en Xamarin Forms con BottomBarPage. Estoy tratando de añadir diferentes opciones en ToolbarItems, pero necesito cambiar el color de fondo del Toolbar, lo he intentado con x:BackgroundColor en the xf:BottomBarPage y al declarar el BottomBarPage pero no me ha dado ningu resultad. Como lo podría hacer?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MyProject.Views.StartPage"
            xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms;assembly=BottomBar.XamarinForms"
            xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views;assembly=MyProject"
            x:Name="TabMenu">


    <xf:BottomBarPage.ToolbarItems x:BackgroundColor="#D60000">
        <ToolbarItem Name="User" Order="Primary" Icon="home.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0" Clicked="User_Clicked"/>
        <!--<ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem2" Order="Primary" Icon="Xamarin.png" Text="Item 2" Priority="1" />-->
    </xf:BottomBarPage.ToolbarItems>

    <xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
        <Views:MainPage 
            ClassId="Home"
            Title="Page1" 
            Icon="Page1.png" 
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:MainPage 
            Title="Page2" 
            Icon="Page2.png"  
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:Graphs 
            Title="Page3"  
            Icon="Page3.png" 
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:MainPage 
            Title="Page4" 
            Icon="Page4.png"
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
        <Views:Info 
            Title="Page5" 
            Icon="Page5.png"
            xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
    </xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
</xf:BottomBarPage>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Estas en la versión en Español del sitio. Por favor traduce tu pregunta o dirígete a la versión en ingles del mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar la propiedad **BackgroundColor** a xf:BottomBarPage de la siguiente manera:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MyProject.Views.StartPage"
        xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms;assembly=BottomBar.XamarinForms"
        xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views;assembly=MyProject"
        x:Name="TabMenu"
        BackgroundColor="Red">

<xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
    <Views:MainPage 
        ClassId="Home"
        Title="Page1" 
        Icon="Page1.png" 
        xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
    <Views:MainPage 
        Title="Page2" 
        Icon="Page2.png"  
        xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
    <Views:Graphs 
        Title="Page3"  
        Icon="Page3.png" 
        xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
    <Views:MainPage 
        Title="Page4" 
        Icon="Page4.png"
        xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
    <Views:Info 
        Title="Page5" 
        Icon="Page5.png"
        xf:BottomBarPageExtensions.TabColor="#D60000"/>
</xf:BottomBarPage.Children>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el color, puedes usar DynamicResource, te explico:
como su nombre lo indica este te puede ayudar cambiar algun recurso de forma dinamica las veces que quieras, en cambio cuando usas StaticResource este siempre se mantendra con el valor que tu le indicaste desde el inicio.

Ejemplo de como usar:

Puedes crear un método para hacerlo, pero te recomiendo que lo pongas en App.cs de la PCL para un fácil mantenimiento.

> App.xaml.cs

```
static void CambiaColor(){

   //Color que inicie es #0d5277 - Azul
   //Puedes definirlo de dos maneras, una es creando otro recurso en tu App.xaml y llamandolo desde aquí
   App.Current.Resources["Toolbar"] = App.Current.Resources["Toolbar_Amarillo"];

// Y la otra es ponerle el color directamente

   App.Current.Resources["Toolbar"] = Color.FromHex("#8fba0e");

}
```

> App.xaml

```
 <Color x:Key="Toolbar">#0d5277 </Color>
 <Color x:Key="Toolbar_Amarillo">#8fba0e</Color>
```

> AlgunaClase.xaml.cs

```
void btnColores(...){

            App.CambiaColor();
}
```

> AlgunaClase.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MyProject.Views.StartPage"
            xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms;assembly=BottomBar.XamarinForms"
            xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views;assembly=MyProject"
            x:Name="TabMenu"
        BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource Toolbar">

...
...
</xf:BottomBarPage>
```